# Tensorflow errors GPU installation

Tags: python, tensorflow

After installing tensorflow GPU, I'm getting the error code below. I've spent hours reviewing existing questions and have not been successful in solving the problem. Thanks.

```
    >>> import tensorflow as tf
    Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

 File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
        return _load(spec)
    ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import

  File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

File "/home/toddahoffman/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

you need cuda and cudnn from nvidea

cudnn, get 7.0: 
https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/form/cudnn-download-survey does require registration

cuda, get 9.0:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive